# Is there a way to find out if a EC2 instance is associated with Auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to find out if an EC2 instance is associated with Auto Scaling Group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [describe-auto-scaling-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-instances.html) function to check which autoscaling group the instance is attached to.

So for example for instance id `i-4ba0837f` you could run the following command

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --instance-ids i-4ba0837f
```

Example response if attached to an autoscaling group is below

```
{
    "AutoScalingInstances": [
        {
            "ProtectedFromScaleIn": false,
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2c",
            "InstanceId": "i-4ba0837f",
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "my-auto-scaling-group",
            "HealthStatus": "HEALTHY",
            "LifecycleState": "InService",
            "LaunchConfigurationName": "my-launch-config"
        }
    ]
}
```

However if it is not attached to any this will be an empty list.

```
{
    "AutoScalingInstances": []
}
```

If this returns no results then that instance is not part of an autoscaling group.

This will also be available in the SDKs:

- [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.describe_auto_scaling_instances)
- [NodeJS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AutoScaling.html#describeAutoScalingInstances-property)
- [Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/autoscaling/AmazonAutoScalingClient.html#describeAutoScalingInstances--)
- [C#](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/AutoScaling/MAutoScalingDescribeAutoScalingInstancesDescribeAutoScalingInstancesRequest.html)
- [PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-autoscaling-2011-01-01.html#describeautoscalinginstances)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following aws cli command:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --instance-ids i-exampleid
```

If the instance is part of an auto scaling group, the result will give you the details.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-instances.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at the instance tags to find out whether it belongs to an ASG. An EC2 in an ASG will always have the `aws:autoscaling:groupName` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [describe-auto-scaling-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-instances.html)

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --instance-ids your-instance-id
```

It will print something like this, if exists

```
{
  "AutoScalingInstances": [
    {
      "InstanceId": "some-instance-id",
      "InstanceType": "m4.large",
      "AutoScalingGroupName": "awseb-some-name",
      "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-1c",
      "LifecycleState": "InService",
      "HealthStatus": "HEALTHY",
      "LaunchTemplate": {
        "LaunchTemplateId": "lt-04a2fffdesa",
        "LaunchTemplateName": "AWSEBEC2LaunchTemplate_foobar",
        "Version": "2"
      },
      "ProtectedFromScaleIn": false
    }
  ]
}
```

if not

```
{
  "AutoScalingInstances": []
}
```